# How to get classname of parent div

Tags: jquery, html

I have a checkbox within several nested divs. On its `OnChange` event I want to get the class name of the parent div/container div `pan-box placeholder`.

The **HTML** structure is something like this

```
<div class="pan-box placeholder" producttype="I" price="34.99" data-productname="$34.99 Standard 15">
    <div class="pan-box-head col-md-12 no-pad">
        <div class="col-md-7 col-sm-12 no-pad pan-price">
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-5 col-sm-12 no-pad">
                <input type="button" value="View Details" class="viewbtn" onclick="CallOfferRenderAction('SP115','TWCv6')">
                <div class="phone">
                    <input type="checkbox" class="SelectedOffer" id="SP115" onchange="SaveCompairedOffers(this);">
                </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I tried  following code, but it returned class-name `phone` which is the immediate parent of checkbox. How can I get the first div class?

```
$(this).parent().prop('className');
```

Comment: You can repeat .parent().parent() etc to go up the chain.  Alternatively, if you know more about the specific note you can use .closest(someSelector) to hit it.

Comment: Though very brittle, you could chain calls to parent() together, however a better solution might be to use closest() and some identifier (class name or data-attribute)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`.parent()` only returns the immediate parent of the element.

You should use `closest()` instead like this:

```
$(this).closest('div.pan-box').prop('className');
```

Answer (score 0):

If I get you, you should do it like this:

```
$(function(){
    "use strict";

    $('.SelectedOffer').on('change', function() {
        console.log($(this).closest('.placeholder').attr('class'));
    });
});
```

for details see [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/50mdnmcp/)